# How to delete a row if it contains specific values "VALUE1" and "VALUE2" in column Z?

Tags: r, dplyr, grepl

I have a large list of data frames and as the heading suggests, would like to find a way to remove all the rows which have both "VALUE1" as well as "VALUE2" in them. For example:

```
weight | height | Z
---------------------------
62      100      NA
65      89       NA
59      88       randomnumbersVALUE1randomtext
66      92       NA
64      90       NA
64      87       randomnumbersVALUE2randomtext
57      84       randomnumbersVALUE2randomtextrandomnumbersVALUE1randomtext
```

would change into:

```
weight | height | Z
---------------------------
62      100      NA
65      89       NA
59      88       randomnumbersVALUE1randomtext
66      92       NA
64      90       NA
64      87       randomnumbersVALUE2randomtext
```

How could I accomplish this for a list of data frames?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyverse)

df |>
  filter(is.na(Z) | !(str_detect(Z, 'VALUE1') & str_detect(Z, 'VALUE2')))
```

Comment: Thank you, it deletes the row which contain both values, but also all rows with NA (these should not be deleted). Any way around this? I used:                                     for(i in 1:length(df)){
df[[i]] <- df[[i]] |>
  filter(!(str_detect(Z, 'VALUE1') & str_detect(Z, 'VALUE2')))
}

Comment: Try `filter(!(str_detect(Z, 'VALUE1') & str_detect(Z, 'VALUE2') & !is.na(Z)))`

Comment: Right. Forgot about the NAs. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you, works like an absolute dream! \../